Is "away" in English a morpheme?
Fromkin's Introduction to Linguistics lists "away" as a English morpheme, which is also a free morpheme and open class word in FIGURE 2.1 Classification of English morphemes on page 49. A morpheme is a minimal linguistic unit, so is it correct that "away" can't be further divided into smaller morphemes?
https://www.etymonline.com/word/away says

away (adv.) Middle English awei, from late Old English aweg, earlier
on weg "on from this (that) place;" see a- (1) + way (n.).

Does it imply that "away" consists of two morphemes: prefix "a" and root "way"? (By definition, prefix and root are morphemes.)

I am not familiar with Fromkin, but it sounds like they give a synchronic analysis. By contrast, your quote from etymonline provides a diachronic online using an etymology. These two approaches are very much not the same.
Etymonline shows that Present-Day English away originates from two separate morphemes, a- and way (cf. afield). However, the meaning of PDE away is not fully compositional (i.e., cannot be derived from the meanings of its component parts), and speakers will not typically be aware of the parts that it, historically speaking, consists of. This is (I presume) why Fromkin describes away as a single morpheme with a meaning of its own.

The meaning is definitely not compositional, but would an average English speaker not be able to work out that away consists of the noun way with the same prefix as in afield, anew, amid, etc. – even if they don’t necessarily intuitively think of it?

@JanusBahsJacquet Sure, and they'd also be able to figure out that "revolve", "devolve", "involve", "evolve" also share a component... but you'd be hard-pressed to find anyone who claims that "-volve" is a morpheme of English.

@JanusBahsJacquet sure, but I wrote “be aware”, not “be able to work out”.

Keelan: Fair enough. Most would probably not be aware of it unless they actively thought about it… but I suspect that also goes for a lot of definitely polymorphemic words as well. // @Deusovi I wouldn’t call -volve a morpheme either, except perhaps a bound morpheme (marginally) – but I wasn’t talking about morphemes, only commenting on the wording that “speakers will not typically be aware of the parts that it … consists of” – whether -volve is a morpheme or not, it’s definitely a part.

@JanusBahsJacquet I would agree that it’s somewhere between “be intuitively aware” and “be able to work out” :)

Thanks. My question is now this. Can a morpheme in Latin become a morpheme in English? How would you tell when yes and when no? Assume that a- and way in away are both Latin morphemes

@Tim yes, what typically happens is that a morphologically complex form lexicalizes or grammaticalizes, so that it is no longer transparent. You may be interested in reading about lexicaluzation, grammaticalization, and univerbation.
